# SQL Inner Join error - new to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, database, inner-join, oledb

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = E:\Computing\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\Database31.accdb");
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Cocktails.CID, Ingredients.Ingredient1" +
            " FROM Cocktails INNER JOIN Ingredients" +
            " ON Cocktails.ID = Ingredients.ID" +
            " WHERE Cocktails.ID = 1",
        connection);

        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            string result = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
            string result2 = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(result + result2);
        }
        connection.Close();
```

I'm new to SQL and trying to pull information from two different tables using an 'inner join', : 'Syntax error in JOIN operation.'
is the error I'm getting and unsure why. Thanks

Comment: what is `Ingredient.ID` and `Cocktail.ID`? Shouldn't it be `Ingredients.ID` and `Cocktails.ID`?

Comment: You have `Cocktail` and `Cocktails` in the query.  Choose the right one.  (Even when you get this right, I doubt the `JOIN` is really on the `id` columns.)

Comment: Are your tables called `Cocktails` and `Ingredients` or are they called `Cocktail` and `Ingredient`?  The query can't seem to decide which.

Comment: To clarify what @GordonLinoff said: check that maybe you also have a `CocktailIngredients` table . If it exists, then you need to use that table as the 'middle man' when joining. It seems **very unlikely** that Cocktails are *equal* to Ingredients, but that is what you imply by linking them directly on both their ID columns.

Comment: hi, yes they were wrong but now I am getting the error ''No value given for one or more required parameters.'

Comment: @ArchiePayne where do you get that error?

Answer (score 0):

Cocktail and Ingredient must be Cocktails and Ingredients, just like you have them in the FROM ... INNTER JOIN line

Answer (score 0):

The table names you specified is wrong.

```
ON Cocktails.ID = Ingredients.ID
```